# AndroidX Migration issue : blacklist / exclude for JAR file

Tags: android, androidx, android-d8

I have a jar file in `libs` which uses `android.support.v4` and I'm trying to migrate to AndroidX.
Now, Gradle sync fails until I set`android.enableJetifier=false` .
But if I set this flag to false then I get D8 error

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompatApi21$MediaItem

What's the right way to solve this migration issue ?

Comment: This cannot be answered unless you'd provide the `dependencies`, which would permit to determine where module `support-v4` needs to be excluded. And this is with high probability not a migration issue, when duplicate support-library classes exist in the package.

Comment: Besides, `exclude` works for `*.jar` just alike it works for any other dependency.

Comment: Check whether the library whose jar you are using has started using androidX. If yes, then you can replace it with a new jar.